# Running my poweshell script produces an error and doesn't onboard new users

Tags: powershell

I am trying to on-board users utilizing Powershell for the company I am working for, however I am coming into an issue that states the directory object is not found. Can anyone assist me with what my error is and how to fix it?

I have tried to remove the city, organizational unit and have tried editing my excel csv file several times, but all tests have failed

```
# Import active directory module for running AD cmdlets
Import-Module activedirectory

#Store the data from ADUsers.csv in the $ADUsers variable
$ADUsers = Import-csv C:\Users\padmin\Documents\users.csv

#Loop through each row containing user details in the CSV file 
foreach ($User in $ADUsers)
{
#Read user data from each field in each row and assign the data to a variable as below

$Username   = $User.username
$Password   = $User.password
$Firstname  = $User.firstname
$Lastname   = $User.lastname
$OU         = $User.ou #This field refers to the OU the user account is to be created in
$email      = $User.email
$streetaddress = $User.streetaddress
#$city       = $User.city
$zipcode    = $User.zipcode
$state      = $User.state
$country    = $User.country
$telephone  = $User.telephone
$jobtitle   = $User.jobtitle
$company    = $User.company
$department = $User.department
$Password = $User.Password


#Check to see if the user already exists in AD
if (Get-ADUser -F {SamAccountName -eq $Username})
{
     #If user does exist, give a warning
     Write-Warning "A user account with username $Username already exist in Active Directory."
}
else
{
    #User does not exist then proceed to create the new user account

    #Account will be created in the OU provided by the $OU variable read from the CSV file
    New-ADUser `
        -SamAccountName $Username `
        -UserPrincipalName "$Username@greenkeyllc.com" `
        -Name "$Firstname $Lastname" `
        -GivenName $Firstname `
        -Surname $Lastname `
        -Enabled $True `
        -DisplayName "$Lastname, $Firstname" `
        -Path $OU `
        #-City $city `
        -Company $company `
        -State $state `
        -StreetAddress $streetaddress `
        -OfficePhone $telephone `
        -EmailAddress $email `
        -Title $jobtitle `
        -Department $department `
        -AccountPassword (convertto-securestring $Password -AsPlainText -Force) -ChangePasswordAtLogon $True

}
}
```

Expected results is to add a user into the proper organizational unit (different office locations) within the local active directory. The actual results are the error below.

```
New-ADUser : Directory object not found
At C:\Users\padmin\Documents\bulk_users1.ps1:41 char:3
+         New-ADUser `
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (CN=Bob Jake,CN=...eenkey,DC=local:String) [New-ADUser], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser

-Company : The term '-Company' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\padmin\Documents\bulk_users1.ps1:51 char:13
+             -Company $company `
+             ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-Company:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Could we see the error that is mentioned in the post?

Comment: The `#` in the middle of the arguments break line continuation

Comment: Hello adminOfThings i have added the error I apologize for that it was supposed to paste the error oddly it didn't

Comment: If you are referring to the line for $city = $user.city, I have removed that line altogether and it still produced the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#` commented out line in the middle of the script breaks your expected line continuation:

```
    -Path $OU `
    #-City $city `
    -Company $company `
```

Put the arguments in to a hashtable and [splat them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) instead:

```
$NewADUserArgs = @{
    SamAccountName = $Username
    UserPrincipalName = "$Username@greenkeyllc.com"
    Name = "$Firstname $Lastname"
    GivenName = $Firstname
    Surname = $Lastname
    Enabled = $True
    DisplayName = "$Lastname, $Firstname"
    Path = $OU
    # City = $city
    Company = $company
    State = $state
    StreetAddress = $streetaddress
    OfficePhone = $telephone
    EmailAddress = $email
    Title = $jobtitle
    Department = $department
    AccountPassword = (convertto-securestring $Password -AsPlainText -Force)
    ChangePasswordAtLogon = $true
}

New-ADUser @NewADUserArgs
```

Now you can easily comment out a single entry in the argument table without worrying about line breaks and all those pesky backticks

Comment: I sincerely appreciate all the effort helping me, sadly I attempted what you posted and got the same error. Is it something with my excel file?

Comment: @Paul.S What is the exact value of `$user.ou` or `$OU`? The "directory object not found" error is likely because you're targeting an OU that doesn't exist

Comment: Maybe post a sample line or two from your csv

Comment: sorry for the late response I was successfully able to determine what the error was. It had to do with my OU path. Thank you all for the amazing help and advice!!!!1